# RACSignal: how to reduce on arbitrarily large combine

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

Consider an example (paraphrased) from the [ReactiveCocoa Introduction](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#introduction), which
enables based on whether the `.password` and `.passwordConfirm` text fields match:

```
RAC(self.enabled) = [RACSignal 
    combineLatest:@[ RACAble(self.password), RACAble(self.passwordConfirm) ] 
    reduce:^(NSString *password, NSString *passwordConfirm) {
        return @([passwordConfirm isEqualToString:password]);
    }];
```

Here we know at compile time how many and what things we are combining, *and* it is useful to destructure/map the "combine" array into multiple arguments to the reduce block. What about when that won't work. For instance, if you want:

```
RAC(self.enabled) = [RACSignal 
    combineLatest:arrayOfSignals 
    reduceAll:^(NSArray *signalValues) {  // made this up! don't try at home.
        // something ...
    }];
```

How do you do this with [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa)?

UPDATE: the accepted answer's comments help explain what I was missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use map:

```
RAC(self.enabled) = [[RACSignal combineLatest:arrayOfSignals]
                     map:^(RACTuple *signalValues) {
                       // something
                     }
                    ];
```

A `RACTuple` can be manipulated in many ways, it conforms `NSFastEnumeration`, it has the `allObjects` method and also the `rac_sequence` method. You can for example combine all boolean values this way:

```
RAC(self.enabled) = [[RACSignal combineLatest:arrayOfSignals]
                     map:^(RACTuple *signalValues) {
                       return @([signalValues.rac_sequence all:^BOOL(NSNumber *value) {
                         return [value boolValue];
                       }]);
                     }
                    ];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I got `map:` to work. The terminology is throwing me off. To my mind, the generalized idea of map is that it preserves cardinality.  If I can map from the combined `RACSignal` to a single value, does that imply its cardinality is 1? If so, the `combineLatest:reduce:` method, which reduces multiple values, seems to muddy things a bit.

Comment: `+combineLatest:` produces tuples, so yes you could say it has a cardinality of 1. The `reduce` variant unpacks the tuple and passes the tuple's individual values to the `reduce` block. `+combineLatest:reduce:` is a convenient way for doing two separate operations: `+combineLatest:` followed by `-reduceEach:`. Does that help explain it?